# Calculate distance between two lat lng without any api

Tags: php, google-maps, distance, zipcode, google-distancematrix-api

I want to calculate distance between two latitude and longitude sets.

**My problem**

I have 2500+ zip codes in a table and I have 10000+ shops, Every shops and zip codes have their lat, lng.

Every shop has their delivery distance in KMS.

I want to save all zip codes of a shop which falls within their delivery distance in a table named *shop_delivery_zips*. I can't use maps at the time on placing order, because shop might not want to deliver at every zips which falls in their delivery distance range.

So, first time i want to insert the data in *shop_delivery_zips* table by checking their delivery distance.

**My solution**

First, I thought that i will write a code which will go to every zips codes and calculate distance between shop lat, lng and zip lat,lng and will save data in *shop_delivery_zips* table, but if i do that, then i have to call the google apis for every time and if i do for all our data, then i have to make 2500*10000 google api calls, which google don't allow in one day, so I can't go with those option.

So, i want to know that is there any way by which i calculate the distance between two lat,lng set. May be by the calculation google use to calculate the same. Please suggest me that solution or any other solution if you know.

Please let me know, if anything is not clear.

Answer (score 3):

I know of this solution to calculate as needed (taken from https://github.com/shafiqpab/distance-between-two-addresses-google-maps-api-php/blob/master/index.php):

```
//Calculate distance from latitude and longitude
$theta = $longitudeFrom - $longitudeTo;
$dist = sin(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * sin(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) +
cos(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * cos(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) *
cos(deg2rad($theta));
$dist = acos($dist);
$dist = rad2deg($dist);
$miles = $dist * 60 * 1.8515;
$unit = strtoupper($unit);
// for units in KM
$kilometers = round($miles * 1.609344, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP).' km';
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

While @tbedner has the correct solution mathematically, you do *not* want to perform this calculation against every location in the list, as the math is very non-trivial.

First you define a simple bounding box, eg:

```
lat BETWEEN $min_lat AND $max_lat
AND
lng BETWEEN $min_lng AND $max_lng
```

Which is very simple and can easily leverage indexes, and *then* you do the complicated math on the much smaller subset of locations that fall inside the box to find the ones that are within the radius you want.

Comment: So, should i get the delivery distance of shop first?. can you explain me with a example or explain the answer a bit. It would be really helpful